# Django how to use if condition inside views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I hope the title is enough to understand what my problem is

this is my html

```
<a href="{% url 'studentenrollment' %}?categoryID={{category.id}}" >{{category.Description}}</a>
```

i have this code inside my views.py

```
def studentenrollment(request):

   categoryID = request.GET.get('categoryID')
   if categoryID == 2:
      ....
      return render(request, 'Homepage/Frontpage.html')
   else:
      ....
      return render(request, 'Homepage/backpage.html')
```

in my case, it always false even thought my **categoryID** is equal to 2. did i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.GET.get('categoryID')` it will always return a string, not an integer. You can either cast it as integer:

```
categoryID = int(request.GET.get('categoryID'))
```

Or you can compare against string value of 2:

```
if categoryID == '2':
```

FYI, please consider using `snake_case` when defining variables as per [**`pep-8`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.